# Default value of a Type in C#

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I am using the following code to convert a string to a specified type. In this example, I have hardcoded the type as `double`, but it could be any type, such as `int`, `long`, `bool`, or others.

However, if the string is empty or `null`, this code will fail. Is there a way to return the default value of the specified type in this case, rather than causing an exception?"

```
var result = ConvertFromString(item, typeof(double));

private object ConvertFromString(string str, Type type)
{
    return Convert.ChangeType(str, type);
}
```

Comment: Why not return `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Activator.CreateInstance` to create an instance of a value type:

```
private static object ConvertFromString(string str, Type type)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        return type.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(type) : null;

    return Convert.ChangeType(str, type);
}
```

`ConvertFromString(null, typeof(int))` will then return `0` (or `default(int)`).

Answer (score 0):

I would make your method generic to return the actual requested type instead of object, to be more type safe. You will find the actual answer to the default thing below too.

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTestMethod()
{
    // to be sure that the decimal sign below is "." and not e.g. "," like in my culture :)
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

    // test
    var result = ConvertFromString<double>("3.14");
    Assert.AreEqual(3.14, result);

    // test
    result = ConvertFromString<double>("blabla");
    Assert.AreEqual(0, result);
}


private TRet ConvertFromString<TRet>(string str)
{
    TRet ret = default(TRet);

    try
    {
        ret = (TRet)Convert.ChangeType(str, typeof(TRet));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // handle error as you wish
    }

    return ret;
}
```